# the title text should align right at the center but it doesn't {html}

Tags: html

here is the code for you to look at.. i only lack this one little thing..

i added pic that will show how it should look out to ease you to understand my english errors thank you for advance.  [this it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUkW0.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 <title>Käyttöjärjestelmät-tehtävät</title>

 <body>
 <table width="800" border="10">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1">

 <text align="center"><h1>Käyttöjärjestelmät - tehtävät</h1> <--- this should be centered right at the center of the blue bar but it's at the center top..)

 </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
 <td class="bgcolor2" style="width:100px;">
 <a href="index.html">Aloitussivu</a><br>
 <a href="historia.html">Historia</a><br>
 <a href="rakenne.html">Rakenne</a><br>
 <a href="tehtavat.html"><b>Tehtävät</b></a>
 </td>
 <td class="bgcolor3" style="height:400px;width:300px;">
 
 <td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1" style="text-align:center;">
 Copyright © <a href="mailto:laineenreiska@kiipula.fi">
mikko.maunula@kiipula.fi</a></td>

 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a website with tabular layout?

Comment: There is no `<text>` element in HTML.

Comment: you should learn how to use sidebars instead of tabular layout

Comment: You have too many syntax errors in you code, you should learn some HTML basics tutorial before you ask. Then create a minimal problem (only thing that is not working, not all your code) and ask again.

Answer (score 0):

There's no end tag of your second row. And the third row (copyright) is not wrapped in `<tr>` at all. `<td>` (columns) elements should always be inside of `<tr>` (rows).

```
<table width="800" border="10">

<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1"><h1 align="center">Käyttöjärjestelmät - tehtävät</h1></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
<td class="bgcolor2" style="width:100px;">
<a href="index.html">Aloitussivu</a><br>
<a href="historia.html">Historia</a><br>
<a href="rakenne.html">Rakenne</a><br>
<a href="tehtavat.html"><b>Tehtävät</b></a></td>
<td class="bgcolor3" style="height:400px;width:300px;">
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1" style="text-align:center;">
Copyright © <a href="mailto:laineenreiska@kiipula.fi">
mikko.maunula@kiipula.fi</a></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Copy paste this into your file and add the background colors

```html
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>Käyttöjärjestelmät-tehtävät</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="100%" border="10">
    <tr style="width: 100%;text-align: center">
      <td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1">

        <text align="center">
          <h1>Käyttöjärjestelmät - tehtävät</h1>
        </text>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="bgcolor2" style="width:100px;">
        <a href="index.html">Aloitussivu</a>
        <br>
        <a href="historia.html">Historia</a>
        <br>
        <a href="rakenne.html">Rakenne</a>
        <br>
        <a href="tehtavat.html"><b>Tehtävät</b></a>
      </td>
      <td class="bgcolor3" style="height:400px;width:300px;">

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1" style="text-align:center; width: 100%">
        Copyright © <a href="mailto:laineenreiska@kiipula.fi">
    mikko.maunula@kiipula.fi</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should definitly avoid using tables for your whole website layout. And also a `text` element does not exist in HTML. Replace that with a `<p>` tag.

Comment: I know but just for the convenience of the user

Comment: okay, am cool with that though if an updated one is needed I can bring it up

Comment: Plus 1. I liked your efforts. Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i was in a hurry to write better question but yeah i have just started coding cause this year we do coding, antennas and physics and this work is the final coding "test" i must complete it but i'm stuck cause all the other pages look different and this one page just won't work as they do..

i'll post another code but this code is already complete and the site working properly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<title>Käyttöjärjestelmät-rakenne</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="800" border="10">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1">
<text align="center"><h1>Käyttöjärjestelmät - rakenne</h1>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="bgcolor2" style="width:100px;">
<a href="index.html">Aloitussivu</a><br>
<a href="historia.html">Historia</a><br>
<a href="rakenne.html"><b>Rakenne</b><br>
<a href="tehtavat.html">Tehtävät</a>
</td>
<td class="bgcolor3" style="height:400px;width:300px;">

<h4>Moduulit</h4>

Käyttöjärjestelmään voi kuulua mikroytimen lisäksi useita käyttöjärjestelmä-moduuleita sijoitettuna joko ydin- tai käyttäjätilaan,  kaikkien toimiessa supervisor-tilassa mutta kahdessa osoiteavaruudessa     (ydin- sekä käyttäjä-tilassa). Toisaalta käyttöjärjestelmä voi muodostua     pelkästään monoliittisesta ytimestä, mikä on alkuperäinen käyttöjärjestelmän     toteutustapa. Tuolloin käyttöjärjestelmä toimii yksinään ydin- ja     supervisor-tilassa.</p><h4>Mikrorakenne</h4>
Uudempi ja nykyään suosituin käyttöjärjestelmärakenne on mikroydin, jossa käyttöjärjestelmä on pilkottu pelkistetyksi ytimeksi sekä         käyttöjärjestelmämoduuleihin, jotka toteuttavat esimerkiksi         muistinhallinnan, tiedostojärjestelmät ja verkkoprotokollat. Koska     pelkistetty ydin toimii yksinään ydintilassa ja muut käyttöjärjestelmän osat käyttäjätilassa, joudutaan järjestelmäkutsun tullessa tietoa siirtämään tarvittaessa eri moduulien välillä että ydintilan kautta kierrätettynä vaihtaen tieto ydintilan ja käyttäjätilan osoiteavaruuden rajalla, joka johtaa viiveisiin käskyjen suorituksessa. Pahimmillaan käyttöjärjestelmä toimii 50 % hitaammin kuin monoliittinen, mutta parhaimmillaan taas vain 10 % hitaammin, nykyisillä tietokoneilla suorituskyvyn eron jääden melkein mitättömäksi.</p>
Mikroytimisen käyttöjärjestelmän suosioon on useampia teoreettisia syitä. Tietoturva sekä helppo ohjelmoitavuus. Erilaiset tutkimukset ovat näyttäneet toteen että tavallisessa ohjelmassa on 1–20 virhettä jokaista 1000 riviä koodia kohden. Käyttöjärjestelmät ovat paljon monimutkaisempia kuin tavalliset ohjelmat tai laitteistoajurit, joissa tyypillisesti on enemmän virheitä tuhannella rivillä koodia kuin muussa osassa käyttöjärjestelmää.</p>
Mikroytimisen rakenteen omaava käyttöjärjestelmä on modulaarinen, ja jokainen moduuli on suojattu vielä toisista moduuleista. Tällöin yhden moduulin kaatuessa vain kyseinen käyttöjärjestelmäpalvelu kaatuu muiden jäädessä toimintaan. Jokainen laiteajuri on myös suojattu, ja tällöin yhden laiteajurin kaatuessa vain kyseinen laite katoaa pois käytöstä siksi aikaa kun moduuli ladataan uudelleen käyttöön.</p>

<h4>Monoliittinen rakenne</h4>

Monoliittisen käyttöjärjestelmän kohdalla virhe ajurissa tai käyttöjärjestelmän toiminnoissa johtaa käyttöjärjestelmän kaatumiseen. Tästä on useimmiten merkkinä "Kernel panic!" -ilmoitus. Monoliittinen käyttöjärjestelmä voi olla myös modulaarinen. Tällöin käyttöjärjestelmä ei ole vain yksi binääritiedosto. Osa toiminnoista ja ajureista on omina tiedostoina, jotka ladataan tarvittaessa RAM-muistiin. Modulaarisuudella saadaan käyttöjärjestelmän kokoa pienennettyä sekä vakautta lisättyä, kun vain tarvittaessa tietyt toiminnot ovat käynnissä. Tämä myös vähentää tarvetta asentaa levylle useita versioita käyttöjärjestelmästä aina erilaisilla asetuksilla eri tilanteisiin, kun modulaarisuuden ansiosta voidaan käyttöjärjestelmän ominaisuuksia vaihdella lataamalla tai poistamalla lennossa moduuleja.</p>
Perinteinen monoliittinen käyttöjärjestelmä on nopea. Se ei kuluta turhaan prosessorin kellojaksoja suorittaakseen sanomavälitystä (overhead) käyttöjärjestelmäpalveluiden välillä vaan suorittaa kaikki käyttöjärjestelmän toiminnot yhdessä osoiteavaruudessa. Tällöin yhden järjestelmäkutsun antaminen toimii nopeammin kuin sanomavälitys (IPC).</p>
Ottaen huomioon monoliittisen käyttöjärjestelmän miljoonat rivit koodia yhdessä osoiteavaruudessa, joiden toimintoa kukaan ei kunnolla ymmärrä kokonaisuudessaan, johtaa se useisiin käyttöjärjestelmätason virheisiin ja tietoturvaongelmiin.</p>
Monoliittisen ja mikroytimen käyttöjärjestelmämoduuleita ei pidä sekoittaa toisiinsa. Monoliittisessa käyttöjärjestelmässä moduuli on aina käännetty tiettyä ytimen versiota vasten. Tämä tuo ongelman. Jos ydin muuttuu, täytyy kaikki moduulit kääntää uudelleen. Moduulien liitos ytimeen on hyvin tiukka eikä niiden toimintaa pystytä tarkkaan havainnoimaan kuin vain käyttöjärjestelmän lähdekoodista. Mikroytimen käyttöjärjestelmämoduulit taas ovat itsenäisiä. Tämä helpottaa käyttöjärjestelmän ohjelmoitavuutta, kun jokainen moduuli voidaan kääntää yksinään tai pelkkä ydin yksinään, ilman tarvetta kääntää kaikkia moduuleja samalla. Moduulit ovat myös löyhästi linkitetty ytimeen, jolloin moduuleja voidaan helposti siirtää järjestelmästä toiseen, ongelmitta jopa käyttöjärjestelmän pienten eroavaisuuksien osalta. Tämä helpottaa käyttöjärjestelmän ohjelmoitavuutta.</td>
</tr>

<td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1" style="text-align:center;">
Copyright © <a href="mailto:mikko.maunula@kiipula.fi">
mikko.maunula@kiipula.fi</a></td>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And now i'm going to post the same code as in the question but i won't delete any line so you can see it complete (not ready tho)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 <title>Käyttöjärjestelmät-tehtävät</title>

 <body>
 <table width="800" border="10">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1">
 <text align="center"><h1>Käyttöjärjestelmät - tehtävät</h1>
 </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
 <td class="bgcolor2" style="width:100px;">
 <a href="index.html">Aloitussivu</a><br>
 <a href="historia.html">Historia</a><br>
 <a href="rakenne.html">Rakenne</a><br>
 <a href="tehtavat.html"><b>Tehtävät</b></a>
 </td>
 <td class="bgcolor3" style="height:400px;width:300px;">
 
<h4>Tiedostojärjestelmä</h4>
<p>Käyttöjärjestelmissä on tuki useille tiedostojärjestelmille, jolloin tallennuslaitteilla olevat tiedostot näytetään hakemistoina ja tiedostoina niiden merkityksen kannalta. Tiedostojärjestelmästä riippuen tiedostot merkitään eri tavoin osion kirjanpitoon erilaisten tarpeiden mukaisesti. Käyttöjärjestelmä hoitaa tallennuslaitteiden, kuten kiintolevyjen kirjoituksen ja lukemisen sekä se huolehtii myös tukemistaan erilaisista tiedostojen käyttöoikeuksista. Käyttöjärjestelmä hallitsee lähes aina useampia erilaisia tiedostojärjestelmiä, muutamasta useisiin kymmeniin. Tiedostojärjestelmän tuki voi olla myös käyttöjärjestelmään kuulumattoman ohjelmiston kuten FUSE:n (Filesystem in Userspace) avulla toteutettu, mutta sekin tarvitsee käyttöjärjestelmältä tuen toimiakseen. Tiedostojärjestelmä voidaan myös luoda yksittäiseen tiedostoon, joita käytetään erilaisissa salausjärjestelmissä.</p>

<h4>Muistinhallinta</h4>
<p>Ettei huonosti käyttäytyvä prosessi sekoittaisi muiden prosessien toimintaa, hallitsee sitä käyttöjärjestelmä ja käyttöjärjestelmän toimesta prosesseilla on yleensä pääsy vain tarvitsemaansa muistialueeseen. Käyttöjärjestelmä huolehtii muistinsuojauksesta sekä siitä, että prosessit saavat tarvitsemansa määrän muistia, keskusmuistista tai mahdollisesta näennäismuistista. Ohjelmaa kirjoittaessa/kääntäessä sen sijaintia muistissa ei vielä tiedetä, sillä muistialue varataan vasta kun ohjelman suorittava prosessi luodaan. Prosesseja voidaan myös suorituksen aikana siirtää muistialueelta toiselle, mahdollisesti jopa keskus- ja näennäismuistin välillä. Ohjelman käyttämä "looginen" osoiteavaruus voi olla suurempi kuin koneessa oleva fyysinen keskusmuistin määrä. Prosessin päättyessä käyttöjärjestelmä vapauttaa prosessin käyttämän osoiteavaruuden ja tarvittaessa muiden prosessien vaatiessa lisää muistia.</p>

<h4>Virtuaalimuisti</h4>
<p>Ohjelman osoiteavaruus ja fyysinen muistiavaruus erotetaan toisistaan. Loogiset osoitteet ja fyysiset muistipaikat yhdistetään toisiinsa prosessikohtaisilla sivutauluilla (engl. page tables). Tiedot voivat sijaita näennäismuistissa josta ne ladataan keskusmuistiin ja keskusmuistin tilan loppuessa sillä hetkellä tarpeettomat muistit kirjoitetaan näennäismuistiin.</p>

<h4>Prosessienhallinta</h4>
<p>Ohjelman käynnistyessä käyttöjärjestelmä luo sille tarvittavan prosessin, muistiavaruuden ja tarvittavat tietorakenteet. Vastaavasti nämä resurssit vapautetaan ohjelman lopetuksen yhteydessä. Käyttöjärjestelmä tarjoaa myös työkalut prosessien tarkkailuun, prosessien lopettamiseen ja prosessien väliseen kommunikointiin.
Moniajon ansiosta tietokoneessa voi samanaikaisesti olla ajossa useampia ohjelmia. Suoritin annetaan vuorotellen vähäksi aikaa eri prosessien (tai niiden säikeiden) käyttöön. Aika pidetään niin lyhyenä, että interaktiiviset ohjelmat näyttävät olevan ajossa koko ajan. Käyttöjärjestelmän vuorottaja pyrkii jakamaan suoritinaikaa tarkoituksenmukaisesti, huomioiden eri prosessien prioriteetin ja luonteen.</p>
 
<h4>Verkkoprotokollat</h4>
<p>Käyttöjärjestelmä toteuttaa OSI-mallin 3. tason (verkkokerros) sekä 4. tason (kuljetuskerroksen) toteutukset toimiessa muiden tietokoneiden/laitteiden kanssa verkossa ja tarjoaa nämä tasot sovellusohjelmien käyttöön. Ylemmät tasot toteutetaan muilla ohjelmistoilla kuten HTTP- tai FTP-palvelinohjelmistolla, P2P- tai Windows Live Messengerin asiakasohjelmilla. Käyttöjärjestelmän tehtävä on ainoastaan tarjota verkko- ja kuljetuskerros muille ohjelmille.</p>
</tr>
 
 <td colspan="2" class="bgcolor1" style="text-align:center;">
 Copyright © <a href="mailto:laineenreiska@kiipula.fi">
mikko.maunula@kiipula.fi</a></td>

 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

there you go

i would really need to complete this to pass this year..